# How to set up cron.yaml for multiple cron jobs with same handler?

Tags: google-app-engine

Here is my `cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
  - description: 'cron trigger create email'
    url: /cron/events/createEmail
    schedule: every 1 hours
    target: cron-jobs-background-cloud-function
  - description: 'cron trigger create user'
    url: /cron/events/createUser
    schedule: every 1 hours
    target: cron-jobs-background-cloud-function
```

`server.js`:

```
function taskHandler() {}

app.get('/cron/events/createEmail', (req, res) => {
  const topicName = req.path.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  console.log('topicName: ', topicName);
  taskHandler(topicName);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/cron/events/createUser', (req, res) => {
  const topicName = req.path.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  console.log('topicName: ', topicName);
  taskHandler(topicName);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Both `cron.yaml` and `server.js`, they are duplicated.

Does `cron service` support path pattern like this:

`cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
  - description: 'cron-jobs-background-cloud-function'
    url: /cron/events/*
    schedule: every 1 hours
    target: cron-jobs-background-cloud-function
```

`server.js`:

```
app.get('/cron/events/*', (req, res) => {
  const topicName = req.path.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  console.log('topicName: ', topicName);
  taskHandler(topicName);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you can't use wildcards in `cron.yaml` but you can use them in `app.yaml` and this should achieve what you would like to do.

Keep your `cron.yaml` like this:

```
cron:
  - description: 'cron trigger create email'
    url: /cron/events/createEmail
    schedule: every 1 hours
    target: cron-jobs-background-cloud-function
  - description: 'cron trigger create user'
    url: /cron/events/createUser
    schedule: every 1 hours
    target: cron-jobs-background-cloud-function
```

Set up your `app.yaml` like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /cron/events/*
  script: [PATH TO APP]
```

And then you can use the one handler for all your cron jobs as you have in your question.

Comment: After read this docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element, the doc says that the value of `script` is `auto`?

Comment: @novaline, I don't use Python and not nodejs so I can't answer that. You should be able to keep whatever is currently in your `app.yaml`.