# how to reuse config in cron.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a lot of cron jobs with same config. I want to use `vars` to reuse some configs.

Here is my try.

`cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
  - description: 'a'
    url: /cron/events/a/b
    schedule: &schedule every 1 hours
    target: &target reuse-cron-config
  - description: 'b'
    url: /cron/events/a/c
    schedule: *schedule
    target: *target
```

But when I ran `gcloud app deploy ./cron.yaml`. It thrown an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-gcp/src/app-engine/standard-environment/reuse-cron-config/cron.yaml]
Anchors not supported in this handler
  in "/Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-gcp/src/app-engine/standard-environment/reuse-cron-config/cron.yaml", line 4, column 15
```

All of my cron jobs have same `target` and `schedule`. How can I solve this? thanks.

**update**

I have a route like this to get params for each cron url:

```
app.get('/cron/events/:topic/:retryTopic', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params); // {topic: 'a', retryTopic: 'b'}
})
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53061394/136598

Comment: @JeffO'Neill I think this case has a little different. I use `req.params` to get `a`, `b` and `c`. So, I have to declare every url in `cron.yaml` file.

Comment: the linked question can work for you.  Your cron request handler can process the url to get the a, b, c params.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill. Yeah. My point is to reuse `target` and `schedule`. that's it. I don't want to declare them in each cron job. Like declare a `var`

Comment: You can't have variables in cron.yaml so the only solution is to reduce the number of entries in cron.yaml and use one handler to process multiple cron jobs.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill I updated my question. Please take a look. So I need declare each cron url. Because each cron url have different `topic` and `retryTopic`

Comment: @novaline: But that's only because you built it that way. So you already know the complete set of (`topic`, `retryTopic`) pairs (you want to create a cron job for each one). What stops you from getting a single cron request at `/cron/events` and in its handler iterate through that complete set enqueueing a task for each such pair (i.e. Alex's answer)? The task handler would process each pair just as the original per-pair cron job would. 1 cron job config, same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap up all of these cron entries into a single entry called 'Hourly tasks' or 'daily tasks' and then the request handler could then launch all of these tasks via the task queue.

This would also help you stay well under the the cap imposed on the total number of cron tasks youre allowed to have

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#limits

> Free applications can have up to 20 scheduled tasks. Paid applications can have up to 250 scheduled tasks.